# Android Method for Parsing Date String to Long

Tags: android, parsing

I'm trying to write a method to convert a date `String` to `Long`. I can't tell if I've written the method incorrectly or if the date formatting in the `SimpleDateFormat` is incorrect. I'm getting my string from an SQLite Database like so:

```
DBAdapter info = new DBAdapter(this);
info.open();
infoStrArray = info.displayEventsInList4();
info.close();
startDateStr = getLongDate(Long.parseLong(infoStrArray[2]));
endDateStr = getLongDate(Long.parseLong(infoStrArray[3]));

textview_TV.setText(startDateStr + ", " endDateStr);
```

In the database the Date String is written like this: "2014_06_11 10:55:00". And so in my getLongDate method, I've written the SimpleDateFormat format like so: `yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss`. Here's the complete method:

```
    public static String getLongDate(long milliSeconds) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
    return sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

}
```

So then, running the code I get the error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: 2014_06_11 10:55:00`. So where's the glitch? Is the method written incorrectly, am I calling the method incorrectly, or is it the date format syntax, or is it something I'm not seeing at all?

Here's my solution after Igle put me on track:

```
        startDateLong = getLongDate3(infoStrArray[2]);
    endDateLong = getLongDate3(infoStrArray[3]);


    textview_TV.setText(String.valueOf(startDateLong) + ", " + String.valueOf(endDateLong));



public static long getLongDate3(String dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss");

    //This creates a date object from your string
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //getTime() always returns milliseconds since 01/01/1970
    return date.getTime();
}
```

Comment: 2014_06_11 10:55:00 is string where is the long data long is for unix timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to parse the string as long.

Instead pass a string to `getLongDate()` like this:

```
public static String getLongDate(string dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss");

    //This creates a date object from your string
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);

    //getTime() always returns milliseconds since 01/01/1970
    return date.getTime();
}
```

Comment: I had to tweak your code, but you put me on the right track - thanks!